# Why do not I see a sample data chart when I pass a date parameter in pentaho cde?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I have created a cde in which I create two date parameter for star date and another for end date. I create the input date select, and in the sql I put the following:

select distinct
    c.country,
    sum(c.creditlimit) AS total_credit_limit
FROM
    customers c,
    orderfact o
WHERE
    c.customernumber=o.customernumber
    AND
    (
        to_char(ORDERDATE,'YYYY-MM-DD')>=${param_start_date}
        AND
        to_char(orderdate,'YYYY-MM-DD')<=${param_end_date}
    )
GROUP BY
    c.country
ORDER BY
    total_credit_limit ASC

Comment: your description is very general.
you can search on google for parameterized dashboard sample and check whether you have followed all the steps properly or not.

Comment: One question, i have to insert any javascript function to catch the value of the simple parameter? because i only draw the graphic with the default value of the simple parameter but when i set other value the graphic ddoesn't change